# Rust compiler error - "maybe missing crate ..."

Tags: rust

I have a project with multiple files which all depend on each other which worked fine. I added another file and added the `use crate::asteroid::Asteroid` syntax to another file.

When I compile it says

> unresolved import "crate::asteroid"

This worked with all the other files. What is wrong?

Project layout:

```
/src/
    asteroid.rs
    command.rs
    direction.rs
    game.rs
    main.rs
    point.rs
    ship.rs
```

Answer (score 4):

The `use` keyword will import only the path specified, so when you `use crate::asteroid::Asteroid` only the Asteroid object will be imported, but not `crate::asteroid`.  In order to import both, you can use:

```
use crate::asteroid::{ self, Asteroid };
```

Here `self` is referring to `crate::asteroid`.  You will then be able to access both `asteroid` and `Asteroid`